Was the Ecdysozoan last common ancestor a priapulid-like organism?
Is it possible that the LCA of all ecdysozoans was priapuilid-like, or very similar morphologically to priapulids, while all the other body plans - arthropods, lobopodians etc were more derived?
Based on the following:

T. Pedum ichnofossil which marks the Cambrian boundary and is described to be similar to traces made by modern priapulid worms
Genetically, scalidophorans are described as sister lineage to all other ecdysozoans
Very early Cambrian scalidophoran worms look almost identical to modern priapulids
This rather insightful video which suggests that the ancestral mouth of arthropods was radiodont-like - circular with teeth similar to a priapulid
Molecular clock studies have revealed that unlike arthropods or nematodes priapulids are slow-evolving and their mitochondrial gene order may be unchanged since the Cambrian.

I guess my question is - morphologically, is the LCA of all ecdysozoans more likely to look like a modern priapulid than a modern insect?

Your intuition is close to what I think is the consensus in the field: that the ecdysozoan LCA had a terminal mouth, worm-like appearance, pseudocoel, maybe scalid-like structures and lacked true segmentation, I'd have to check this against the current literature.

@alephreish And it would have had ecdysis (molting)) as well, right?

Sure. I've posted my answer now.

Indeed, reconstruction of the appearance of the last common ancestor of the crown-group Ecdysozoa which covers the three major clades (extant representatives in parentheses):

Scalidophora (modern priapulids, kinorhychs and loriciferans)
Nematoida (nematodes and nematomorphs)
Panarthropoda (tardigrades, onychophorans, arthropods)

is uncontroversial thanks to a large degree to the fact that the phylogenetic relationships between them have been resolved with phylogenomics: Scalidophora + (Nematoida + Panarthropoda). Position of Loricifera accroding to molecular data has been controversial but the (morphologically transparent) monophyly of Scalidophora is now largely established. The ancestral morphological characteristics of the LCA (not necessarily synapomorphies) of the crown-group are:

ecdysis
pseudocoel
circum-oral brain
terminal mouth
protonephridia
digestive system opening at both ends
vermiform annulated but unsegmented body
pharyngeal armour (cf. priapulid pharyngeal teeth and various putatively homologous structures across those ecdysozoans that have them)
maybe: circum-oral armour (cf. scalids) although homologization is not certain across the different taxa
proboscis but maybe not introvert covered with scalids -- notice however that introvert is in fact present in scalidophorans and nematomorph larvae
maybe: a mouth cone which is present in scalidophorans, nematomorph larvae and tardigrades

One of the open questions is the position of the several priapulid-like fossils (see one of the attempted reconstructions here). One of the the most prominent and better studied taxa among them are palaeoscolecids which have an armoured introvert, a long nematoid-like body and cuticular plates which some see as homologous to cuticular plates of Cambrian lobopods. They might turn out to be stem-group priapulids, stem-group scalidophorans or maybe they diverged even before.
Reconstruction of the ancestral body plan of the total-group Ecdysozoa (i.e. including taxa diverging before the crown group) is more problematic as it depends a lot on the interpretation on the morophological features and position of some critical fossils. For example, Acosmia, has been demonstrated to lack a true introvert and pharyngeal armature which lowers the probability of these structures to be present in the LCA of total-group Ecdysozoa. Analogously other, such "priapulid-like" forms as Ancalagon and Fieldia which might belong to stem-group Ecdysozoa have a non-retractable proboscis as well.
Finally, the alien-looking Saccorhytida have been proposed to be sister group to (the rest of?) Ecdysozoa which has a profound effect on the reconstruction of the ancestral body plan of the group but the evidence that they belong to Ecdysozoa is controversial.
To answer your question directly, whether the LCA of Ecdysozoa was priapulid-like: not exactly. It must have had a proboscis but maybe not an introvert (this depends on whether the introvert of nematomorph larvae is a remnant of the same structure as in scalidophorans and whether we are talking about crown-group or total-group Ecdysozoa), certainly not an introvert armoured with scalids which is a synapomorphy of Scalidophora.

Thank you! I didn't know about Acosmia maotiania from the article you linked - https://bmcecolevol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12862-020-01720-6, but it sounds very interesting. My guess now is that Acosmia maotiania was either the urecdysozoan or as closely related to it as you can get.

Yes, it does look like this (alongside Ancalagon and Fieldia). Notice that I've corrected the points concerning introvert and mouth cone in the crown-group Ecdysozoa. I'll refresh my memories on these points and add more details and citations later. The situation with the circum-oral armour is also quite complicated.

Thank you, and I have added one more question about deuterostomic development (radial cleavage) in the ecdysozoan LCA - https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/115104/23100
