Is radial cleavage (deuterostomy) ancestral to ecdysozoans?
Apparently Priapulids have deuterostomic development according to this paper:

Priapulids mostly reproduce by external fertilization, and the embryos undergo holoblastic radial cleavage, considered to be the ancestral cleavage mode in ecdysozoans.

Their conservative morphology might make them similar to the ecdysozoan common ancestor.
If Priapulids have deuterostomic development (radial cleavage), does that mean that:

The ELCA (Ecdysozoan last common ancestor) had radial cleavage and deuterostomic development
Insects and nematodoes have protostomy as a derived feature, not ancestrally inherited from the ELCA?


In the subsequent paper the authors make exactly this claim. I'm not an expert but deuterostomy is encountered in several unrelated taxa and I think it is more likely that deuterostomy in Priapulus and some arthropods evolved secondarily from ancestral protostomy (or amphistomy?), see Nielsen's review.

Note a related question here: https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/115095/22392. @alephreish based on the collection of data, it seems that deuterostomy (or deuterostome-like development) might be the ancestral condition, from which protostomy arose, and then deuterostomy re-evolved within some protostomes. Am I getting my ordering right? Not an expert!
